# C# implementation of RapidShare Perl upload script

Tags: c#, perl, upload, rapidshare

Is there any C# implementation of [RapidShare Perl](http://images.rapidshare.com/software/rsapiresume.pl) upload script? I have tested some articles like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Upload_To_Rapidshare.aspx) one, but doesn't works for me.

Comment: Why do you want c# version instead of perl version ?

Comment: Because I'm going to use in my C# app! I know nothing about of Perl.

Comment: If you need this program very soon you can compile perl code and use the "exe" through c#

Comment: But there is no flexibility in your solution!

Comment: yeah it's just a "dirty quick" solution ... Because this perl script is too long to translate easily in csharp ! Sorry atm i don't have any other solution

Comment: You know about perl? You can suggest me if i want to translate?

Comment: Hey can u compile perl script? i can't figure it out!

Comment: There are perlcc & perl2exe but never test. But I have tested the Perl Dev Kit from [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/perl-dev-kit) ... It's commercial kit nevertheless there is trial.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I understand that you need to implement this in your C# app. Rapidshare has a .net library.

See for an example here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Rapidshare-Download_Class.aspx